# Proving if a function $f$ is differentiable and $f'(x)\ne0$ at all $x$, then it is one-to-one

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-writing

Here's what the problem reads:

Suppose that the function $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, and $f'(x)\neq 0$ for any $x \in (a,b)$.  Prove that $f$ must be one-to-one.

---

This looked easy at first, but I'm having a lot of trouble cracking the proof just by examining the definitions.  If someone could nudge me in the right direction, that would be extremely helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you know that $f'$ never reaching $0$ implies that $f$ is monotonic?

Comment: True, but I would caution that it is a one-way implication.

Comment: I've changed the title to something that is not false and better reflect the question, and removed the mention of continuity as differentiability implies it. (Note that what is mentioned in the body of the question is not that $f$ is continuous, but rather that it is continuous *even at the end points of the interval*, which is where we do not have differentiability.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint:** Assume that $f$ takes the same value in two points, and apply the mean value theorem.

Comment: After applying the mean value theorem this way, it would equal zero, but it violates the premise that f'(x) =/= 0.  What does this mean for my proof?

Comment: @HeathHuffman It means you have produced a proof by contradiction.

Comment: @Potato Did I do it right, or did I miss something important?

Comment: @HeathHuffman I'm not sure, since you have not presented a proof. Do you know what a proof by contradiction is? Do you see how Harald's hint helps you write one?

Answer (score 4):

Assume the opposite.

If $f$ is not one-to-one then there must exist the points $\alpha,\beta\in(a,b)$ such that $f(\alpha)=f(\beta)$.

Now we apply the [mean-value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem).

This inescapably concludes that $$f'(c)=\frac{f(\beta)-f(\alpha)}{\beta-\alpha}$$
And if $f(\alpha)=f(\beta)$ then $f(\alpha)-f(\beta)=0$
$$\implies f'(c)=\frac{f(\beta)-f(\alpha)}{\beta-\alpha}=\frac{0}{\beta-\alpha}=0$$
Which contradicts our assumption of there being no $f'(x)=0\qquad x\in(a, b)\qquad\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

I would consider proving the contrapositive. Show that if f is not one-to-one those properties cannot hold. I.e. if f is surjective and not injective what does that say about the derivative (if it exists) and vice-versa.